# Looping over a nested list (2d Matrix) and running a condition check for the values of specific indices that are designated within a second list

Tags: python, matrix, nested-lists

I've been trying to wrap my head around this, and I think I'm failing to understand the core fundamentals of nested loops. My question isn't just about what the answer is, but I would really appreciate and explanation of how to think and deal with a problem like this. This is for coursework, but I want to really understand why I'm having this issue and how python works when it comes to this regard.

I have the code below:

**What I have so far**

```
import numpy as np

marks = np.array([[66, 26, 54, 80, 56, 42, 56, 60],
        [34, 63, 90, 98, 78, 65, 45, 54],
        [94, 87, 92, 80, 79, 90, 98, 89]])

def canGraduate(arr, sNum):

studentId = marks[sNum]
passedCompulsoryModule = False
passedModuleCounter = 0
if (studentId[1] >= 40) & (studentId[4] >= 40):
    passedCompulsoryModule = True
    for element in studentId:
        if element >= 40:
            passedModuleCounter += 1
    if (passedModuleCounter >= 3) & (passedCompulsoryModule == True):
        print(f'Student has passed {passedModuleCounter} modules and both compulsory modules. They have passed.')
else:
    print("Student has failed the course.")

canGraduate(marks, 0)
canGraduate(marks, 1)
canGraduate(marks, 2)
```

What this code does, is that when I call the function with the list as marks, and specifically targetting the 1st index of the outer list, it will run through the loop and make a simple condition check on the values. This works fine. It prints out:

```
Student has failed the course.
Student has passed 7 modules and both compulsory modules. They have passed.
Student has passed 8 modules and both compulsory modules. They have passed.
```

Just as I need it to.

**My main problem**

I want to run the same code, however I want to instead create a list which we will call compulsoryModules, enter two values which are 1 and 4, which are the indexes that I am using to run the initial if statement within the code block above. So we have the below code:

```
compulsoryModules = [1, 4]
```

I'm struggling however to use this variable as is, because I cannot seem to find a way to have two indexes within the same variable? I can put just a single index, such as [1] or [4] and it will be fine but I was tasked to put it within a list.

The compulsoryModule list will be used as a third arg while calling the function to check. So ideally, I could have multiple lists of different varying indexes and can use them to call a variety of lists to focus on different indexes.

So this will look like:

```
def canGraduate(arr, sNum, lst):
```

with the condition looking something like:

```
if studentId[lst] >= 40:
```

However the error I seem to be getting is:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

This is odd to me, because I'm only asking for two single indicies to be checked. I don't want to specifically check them all, or any of them. It needs to be those two indicies.

I have tried using what was recommended within this site:
https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-access-multiple-indices-of-a-list-in-python

Which was to use a map function to try and target both indicies. But doing that seemed to target the outer list and so I was having an error because the [4] index was throwing it out of bounds. I thought to try and put this within a loop to access the inner lists, however I seemed to be having the same issue.

I've been looking online to see if I could figure it out, but I'm at a loss at this point.

What's the way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is, you can just replace your

```
if (studentId[1] >= 40) & (studentId[4] >= 40):
```

with

```
for cm in compulsoryModules:
    if studentId[cm] < 40:
        passedCompulsoryModules = False
        break
```

As you can see, you need to loop over the elements of `compulsoryModules`. You cannot pass a whole list as an index, you pass single items in a loop.

Comment: Oh, ofcourse! So I was trying to initially loop over the whole list and not the elements. Thank you for the explanation, this helped. Also making it so it deals with the false element first is a better way than dealing with it last seems to be a better way as well. Thank you for your help.